# Axios 404 error, two different localhosts

Tags: reactjs, post, server, axios, put

I'm running the server on localhost:3000 and my React app is on localhost:8080. I've looked at other Stack Overflow questions and it seems setting the full url worked but it's not in my case.

sever.js

```
const sendAxie = require("./sendAxie");

const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "public");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.post("/send-axie", (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body);
  console.log("in send-axie");
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server is up on " + PORT);
});
```

app.js

```
axios
  .put("http://localhost:3000/send-axie", { axieID })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("in catch");
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Console:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/send-axie 404 (Not Found)
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your express app, you have wrote a `post` api. In react you are calling a `put` api. Change that to `post`

Answer (score 1):

as I understand it, you make a `PUT` request, but in your routes only `POST`. You need to add this

```
app.put("/send-axie", (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body);
  console.log("in send-axie");
});
```